# Lock the rotation of the Scopes and Welcome screen in portrait mode on tablet

Tags: unity, ubuntu-touch, orientation

Last update Ubuntu Touch on my Nexus 7 to 16.04 (r3) lock the rotation of the Scopes and Welcome screen in landscape mode.

This is extremely inconvenient for me. Is it possible to unlock rotation or lock it to portrait mode instead landscape mode?